# Is there any way to auto generate UML diagrams in Spring Tool Suite IDE

Tags: spring, uml

I have created my Project in Spring Tool Suite (STS). I need to auto generate UML diagrams like class, sequence, activity and domain diagrams. How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [ObjectAid](http://www.objectaid.com) plugin for Eclipse.
It should work with STS.

Comment: Is there any free similar plugin?

Answer (score 0):

There are a log of plugins that claim to do this but none are successful. Its easy for normal Java Code but for a STS project which builds on Maven. Not possible as of yet!

Answer (score 0):

If anybody is still interested in this topic, you can check out Rebel plugin with StarUML.

More details can be found here: https://www.archetypesoftware.com/.